# How to execute a method in another file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to separate all of my SQLite code in a separate .m file (called SQLiteDB.m, along with the .h file).  I am calling one of the methods from another file, :ReaderAppDelegate.m".  Code is:

```
//  create the d/b if it doesn't exist
[self checkForDatabase];
```

In ReaderAppDelegate.h, I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@class ReaderViewController;

@interface ReaderAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    ReaderViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ReaderViewController *viewController;

- (void)checkForDatabase;
//- (void)SQLiteConnection: (NSString *)defaultDBPath;
@end
```

Obviously, it can't find it, because it's sitting in SQLiteDB.m.

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"

@implementation SQLiteDB

@synthesize db, dbPath, databaseKey;


//--------------    check for database or create it    ----------------|

+ (void)checkForDatabase  {

    // Get the path to the database file
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ppcipher.s3db"];

    // Open the database file
    const char *cDatabasePath = [databasePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(sqlite3_open(cDatabasePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK)  {


    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: A good resource for object-orientated programming with objective-c http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to import SQLiteDB.h in your ReaderAppDelegate.m file. And make sure

```
+ (void)checkForDatabase;
```

is declared in the header, SQLiteDB.h.

Complete example:

ReaderAppDelegate.h

```
@class SQLiteDB;

@interface ReaderAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
     ...
     SQLiteDB *myDB;
}
```

ReaderAppDelegate.m

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"

@implementation
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
      myDB  = [SQLiteDB checkForDatabase];
 }
```

SQLiteDB.h

```
@interface SQLiteDB : NSObject {
      ...
}

+ (void)checkForDatabase;
```

Comment: Quick naming convention. It's probably better to call "checkForDatabase" something like "sharedDatabaseInstance." In the latter one, under Cocoa's naming conventions, it's implied that the method will return a singleton instance of SQLiteDB.

Comment: I don't know if we're making progress or not... here is the latest build errors:  (http://imgur.com/Ft8jy).  Here is the source for ReaderAppDelegate.m (http://imgur.com/BTkUP).  And finally, here is the source for SQLiteDB.h (http://imgur.com/iobae).

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to this code in ReaderAppDelegate.m...  please excuse my ignorance, but exactly "where" does this go?

`- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
      myDB  = [SQLiteDB checkForDatabase]; `

Comment: It goes in the implementation file, as shown above. The compiler problem you posted an image for is in the highlighted line. It should be SQLiteDB *db.

Comment: Still not building... here is error: (http://imgur.com/85vvk).  Here is source for ReaderAppDelegate.m (http://imgur.com/JpHhC), here is source for SQLiteDB.h (http://imgur.com/C8Oa0), and finally SQLiteDB.m (http://imgur.com/HXqic).

Comment: (1) In SQLiteDB.h: You declare the ivar type of 'db' to be SQLiteDB *, but the property type to be sqlite3 *. You probably want the ivar type to be sqlite3 * as well.
(2) You still didn't add the pointer to the property declaration like I said above.
(3) You have two different applicationDidFinishLaunching methods. Consolidate into one. You probably want to get rid of the [[SQLiteDB alloc] init] stuff now that you're using "checkForDatabase" as the initializer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am totally lost when you say "You still didn't add the pointer to the property declaration like I said above."  Can you give me the exact line of code you are referring to? (cause I thought I had it, but appearently not).  Thanks for your time, Stephen... I really, really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure. Sorry for not being clear. In ReaderAppDelegate.h, the property declaration for myDB should read: @property (nonatomic, retain) SQLiteDB *myDB. The asterisk denotes that the property is a pointer to a SQLiteDB.

Comment: Getting closer!  Here is ReaderAppDelegate.m (http://imgur.com/JcN4y), ReaderAppDelegate.h (http://imgur.com/MJDIa), SQLiteDB.h http://imgur.com/2boQb) and finally SQLiteDB.m (http://imgur.com/1DVlO).  I also just ordered a book "Cocoa in a Nutshell" which hopefully will help me... the current book I have "iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" is almost worthless as a reference.

Comment: Right now, sharedDatabaseInstance isn't returning anything. But when you call the method in your AppDelegate, you're storing the returned value in myDB. In sharedDatabaseInstance, you'll want to return the singleton instance of SQLiteDB. I'd recommending reading "Creating a Singleton Instance": http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32

Comment: Thanks... do you have a PayPal account?

Comment: I do, but I'm just helping you work through your problems as you start. No need for anything in return!

Answer (score 0):

Don't it has a header - `SQLiteDB.h`. If yes, include it. Have a pointer to the interface in `ReadAppDelegate` which gets initialized and call the method like -

```
[ instance SQLiteConnection:defaultPath ] ;
```

If it's part of another interface, you cannot declare it to be the member of current interface and access the other. Instead pass the message to instance.

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"
@interface ReaderAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    // ....
    SQLiteDB *instance; // You need to dealloc it because it manages resources.
}
```